# How to update inactive Window gracefully through cli?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, kde

If I am working, say, on a text file, but have a Firefox window at another workspace that I want to update regularly: how can I, through the command-line, perform this action?

The text file is independent from Firefox. There's only one Firefox window open, so the comment below works as it if.

All happens under the same session and user.

Right now, I simply switch to it regularly using a script with `wmctrl -a Firefox && xdotool key --clearmodifiers F5` and back with a similar command, but this interrupts my workflow.

Comment: Please provide more information.  You give us so little to work from.  You don't actually come out and SAY that the text file is or isn't the same file being shown in your browser on another machine.  You don't tell us what operating environments (although one could *guess*) by your commands.  Is another workspace another machine or another login instance on the same machine?  It might seem simple to you but the info leaves many open questions for me.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Reading the docs for xdotool, might you be able to swap `wmctrl` for the `--window Firefox` ? dont know if it takes focus though

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: updated.

Comment: As you can see by the answer provided by the mighty @harrymc , one could not even determine the operating system based on your question.  Thanks for updating it.  *Someone* will *probably* give you a good answer. :)

Comment: If it is indeed a text file, there are so many ways to determine that the file was updated and respond accordingly.  [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101271/open-a-text-file-in-a-terminal-and-auto-refresh-it-whenever-it-is-changed) is a nice thread that might help.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: well, using `wmctrl` might have helped to guess it. Anyway, explicit is better than implicit, so the question had to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows**

I Understand that you wish periodically to refresh the contents of
a Firefox process. For simplicity I'll assume that only one Firefox
process is running, but you may instead use the title to find
this Firefox instant.

The tool I'll use is the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will start a timer on pressing
<kbd>F9</kbd> that will send the F5 key to the Firefox process
every 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds).
Pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> will stop the timer:

```
F9::
SetTimer, sendF5, 5000
return
F10::
SetTimer, sendF5, Off
return

sendF5:
if WinExist("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
  Send, {F5}
return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

**For Linux**

Some projects that are equivalent to AutoHotKey under Linux :

- [autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey)
- [AHK_X11](https://github.com/phil294/AHK_X11)
- [Keysharp](https://bitbucket.org/mfeemster/keysharp/src/master/)

Some more possibilities are discussed in the post
[AutoHotKey for Linux?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/m09mnr/autohotkey_for_linux/)

Comment: This was actually about Linux

Comment: Oups. I added some stuff for Linux, but I haven't myself used these projects.

Comment: AutoKey would do this, but it would do it like you would do it manually (unless you're very good with Python), so your screen would jump around while it was working. xdotool is probably a better candidate for this. It should be able to interact with a window that's not currently displayed on your desktop. By using command chaining, you can get the widow ID and then send that window a Ctrl+R or whatever.
However command chaining involves a bit of a learning curve and it's tricky to debug, so be prepared to spend some effort on it.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, with AHK_X11, you can use the same code like you would on Windows if you prefer to keep the window in the background:

```
SetTimer, refresh, 10000
Return

refresh:
ControlSend,, {F5}, Firefox
Return
```